# Window screenshot using WinAPI

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, sendmessage

How to make a screenshot of program window using WinAPI & C#?

I sending `WM_PAINT (0x000F)` message to window, which I want to screenshot, `wParam = HDC`handle, but no screenshot in my picturebox. If I send a `WM_CLOSE` message, all waorking (target window closes). What I do wrong with `WM_PAINT`? May be HDC is not PictureBox (WinForms) component? P.S. `GetLastError() == ""`

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern Int64 SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
  .....

SendMessage(targetWindowHandle, 0x000F, pictureBox.Handle, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: No. I need to screenshot not active window, and without making them active. Just send WM_PAINT to them, and get response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pictureBox.Handle` is a window handle, not a DC handle. There are several guides online for doing screenshots. One is [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/screencaptures/article.php/c6139/). See also @In silico's answer.

Comment: As will be to write then?
To copy the image in any place

Answer (score 1):

You can also take screenshot using purely managed code without the need for interop. The following code will take a snap of a 100x100 area of the screen, of course you can adjust to the full screen. The key function is `Graphics.CopyFromScreen`

```
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100,100);
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
  {
    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(100, 100));        
  }
  pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/