# Taking screenshot of a partially hidden window in a programmatic way

Tags: c#, .net, screenshot

Is it possible to get a screenshot of a window that is not on the top, i.e. if it is partially hidden by another window, without bringing it to the top?

Comment: You can try [sending `WM_PRINT / WM_PRINTCLIENT`](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/327506-forcing-a-hidden-window-to-paint-to-an-arbitrary-dc/) to the window so it "prints" to an HDC supplied by you. However this won't work for every application so you'll need to test it yourself (and do some research on how to call it from .NET).

Comment: A delphi window from your own process, or another window?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not trivial to take a screen-shot in C# at all, you can create a graphics object based on the current window or viewport and capture that, but its not what you're asking for.

This

[Screenshot of Hidden Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117074/screenshot-of-hidden-window)

might help, but you'd have to do this with Interop code anyway.

I dare say that it's not a common thing that is supported as really, one program has no business knowing what's being displayed in another program; it's potentially a nasty exploit.

Comment: An added problem is that the hidden window doesn't receive `WM_PAINT` requests for the hidden parts. Taking a screenshot requires having it repaint those parts, which is easiest by first bringing the window on top again. However, on Windows-7, the taskbar "knows" all contents for mouse hover, perhaps there's another way?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to take screenshot, if it is your application you can use `Control.DrawToBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle targetBounds);` of the form object.

If it is other application window, you can try un-managed way to get the UI of window. I dont remember all the methods but I have tried and it was working. Probably `GetWindow` and `SendMesage` with  `WM_PRINT / WM_PRINTCLIENT`