# Taking screenshots of partially hidden windows from .NET WPF applications

Tags: c#, wpf, screenshot

I am working on a program that starts several other c# WPF applications and checks wether there are errors (using .NET Automation Services / UITesting).

One of the requirements of it is to take a screenshot of the main window and to put it into a word document. I alread got it working quite fine when it´s one application at a time (using code from this site: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/) , but as soon as i am using parallelism (say, checking 5 applications in a parallel manner), i am running into the problem that the screenshots of the windows may be overlapped by other windows that just popped up or that are always brought to the front (e.g. splash screens). Bringing the window to the front does not really help.

There was an older similar thread not directly regarding to WPF applications, and sadly, without a clear solution: [Taking screenshot of a partially hidden window in a programmatic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037410/taking-screenshot-of-a-partially-hidden-window-in-a-programmatic-way)

Is there a way to get a "clean" screenshot, may be with the use of the windows AutomationElement instance?

Comment: In WPF you can get a "Screenshot" even if the Control isn't even visible, you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx

Comment: Sorrry, i'm not sure how that would work with the WPF controls of external processes. How would i get a valid control reference to use that?

Comment: if you come from a second process you need to inject some code into the process

Comment: another idea, you could bring the window to front before taking the screenshot