# Saving bitmap/"screenshot" of form not working when form is not shown

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I am developing a windows forms application with multiple forms. I would like to print one of the forms as an image file.

I am using this example: [click](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4650-Save-e-Form-o-er-controls-Bitmap.aspx)

I have a form with various labels, textboxes, and a button. When I run `SaveAsBitmap` by pressing the button, the form and its elements is correctly saved as a bmp file (just as if you took a screenshot of it and saved as an image).

Now, I have another form which is **not** to be shown to the user. (It's a form with no form border style.)
I would like to do the bmp saving on this form instead of the other. But no matter where in the code of this form I put the `SaveAsBitmap` method, it only saves the background of the form (no items such as labels).
However, if I put `this.ShowDialog()` somewhere to show the form, and then afterwards run the `SaveAsBitmap` method, it works as it should.

*So the main point here is the fact that it does not work correctly when the form is not shown.*

When using the `SaveAsBitmap` method, I write: `SaveAsBitmap(this, "C:\\test.bmp");`

Any help appreciated!

Comment: this has been asked so many times... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117074/screenshot-of-hidden-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me;

```
theForm.hide();
...
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(theForm.Width, theForm.Height)) {
   theForm.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
   bitmap.Save(@"c:\null\ss.bmp");
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Note to others: before calling Hide() I call Show().